# How to fix google maps z-index issue

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have drawn a circle and and some polygons using addGeoJson. The problem is some of the polygons are drawn above the circle and some are below. How to fix this issue? I want to draw the circle on top of all the polygons. Here is my code

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng());
var mapOptions = {
    zoom:9,
    center:latlng,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
map1 = new google.maps.Map(mapcontainer, mapOptions);


var circleOptions = {
    fillOpacity:0,
    strokeColor: '#000000',
    strokeWeight:2,
    strokeOpacity:1,
    center:map1.getCenter(),
    radius:2000,
    map:map1
};

circleRadius = new google.maps.Circle();
circleRadius.setOptions(circleOptions);

var listOfPolygons = loadPolygons();

//drawing polygon layers
var layer = new google.maps.Data();
var url = 'url/to/cords';
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {'codes': listOfPolygons},
    success:function(data) {
        layer.addGeoJson(data);
        layer.setMap(map1);
        layer.setStyle({
            strokeColor: '#6da57a',
            strokeOpacity:.4,
            strokeWeight:1,
            fillColor: '#7bd490',
            fillOpacity:.6
        });
    }
});
```

See the screenshot
[image]

Comment: Can you provide sample polygons (and other data) to reproduce the issue (a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question)

Comment: why negative??? whats wrong with the question? See the black circular line, somewhere is above the polygon somewhere its under it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the `zIndex`-options and give the circle a higher zIndex than the data-features.

```
var circleOptions = {
    fillOpacity:0,
    strokeColor: '#000000',
    strokeWeight:2,
    strokeOpacity:1,
    center:map1.getCenter(),
    radius:2000,
    map:map1,
    zIndex:1//<----here
};

//........


layer.setStyle({
        strokeColor: '#6da57a',
        strokeOpacity:.4,
        strokeWeight:1,
        fillColor: '#7bd490',
        fillOpacity:.6,
        zIndex:0//<-----here
    });
```